# Fopen to a remote php script

Tags: php, fopen

i have to download a file created from a php script.
i tried this:

```
fopen('www.example.com/download.php?key=value', 'rb');
```

but i stille get a *"failed to open stream"* error.
how can i do that? If I browse to the url i get the file without problems...

EDIT: sorry, i forgot a piece of the string :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see multiple issues with you request:

1. <del>You need to specify the open mode. In your case only `'r'` applies because you only want to read.</del>
2. You need to specify the protocol. In your case "http".
3. You need to have URL wrappers enabled. Do a `phpinfo()` and look if `allow_url_fopen` is set to `On`.
4. You probably wanted [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) anyway.
5. You should enable error reporting and read the error messages. That will help you track the problem faster.
6. Don't forget to `fclose` if you decide to use `fopen`.

Example:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/download.php?key=value');
```

You should also read about [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) in the Manual.

Comment: here it is! i forgot the protocol. ups! -.-

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to read the usage for `fopen` first, here is an example usage:

```
fopen ("http://www.example.com/", "r");
```

r = read, that might be causing your failure.

Comment: yeah, i did it in that way, i only forgot to paste correctly here ^_^